# Magento 2: Less :extend() not adding the mixin

Tags: css, magento, less, magento2

I'm encountering an issue where I'm attempting to apply `.lib-clearfix()` to an class by using an extend. The issue is the extend itself does work, but the extend will not apply the mixin. The relevant files and css below:

{theme-path}/web/css/source/**_sources.less**

```
@import '_variables.less';
@import (reference) '_extends.less';
@import '_typography.less';
@import '_layout.less';
```

{theme-path}/web/css/source/**_extends.less**

```
@abs-add-clearfix: {
    .lib-clearfix();
};

.abs-add-clearfix {
    @abs-add-clearfix();
}
```

lib/web/css/source/lib/**_utilities.less**

```
.lib-clearfix() {
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
    }
    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

{theme-path}/{Module}/web/css/source/**_module.css**

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
  .header.panel:extend(.abs-add-clearfix) {
    ...
  }
}
```

`.header.panel`, as written does not render the `.lib-clearfix()` styles. However, if in `_module.less` I alter `header.panel` to --

```
.header.panel {
  .lib-clearfix();
}
```

-- it works as intended; the clearfix styles are applied. To test whether the extend was even being parsed, I altered `@abs-add-clearfix` to and reverted the `.header.panel` css.

**LESS**

```
@abs-add-clearfix: {
  color: blue;
};

.abs-add-clearfix {
    @abs-add-clearfix();
}

.header.panel:extend(.abs-add-clearfix) {
  ...
}
```

**Output**

```
.header.panel {
  color: blue;
}
```

So, I fail to understand why calling `.lib-clearfix()` through an extend fails, though other css within that extend apply correctly, and why calling `.lib-clearfix()` within the `.header.panel` selector succeeds where the extend failed.

Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Jonathan Eltgroth

Comment: No.  I've unfortunately moved away from Magento for work since then.  I was never able to figure out why it didn't work.